# Xenserver 6.2 cannot send alert using gmail smtp

Tags: xenserver, gmail, ssmtp, alert

I'm using Xenserver 6.2 and configured ssmtp.conf an mail_alert.conf in order to receive alerts through email. I followed the instructions on http://support.citrix.com/servlet/KbServlet/download/34969-102-706058/reference.pdf document. I'm using gmail smtp to send the emails. When i try:

```
[root@xen /]# ssmtp emailaddress@domain.com
```

from the command line and try to send the email, no problem. It is right on the way. But when i set some VM to generate alerts, alerts are generated. I see in XenCenter but emailing is not working. I see this in /var/log/maillog file:

```
May 27 16:17:09 xen sSMTP[30880]: Server didn't like our AUTH LOGIN (530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. 18sm34990758wju.15 - gsmtp)
```

From command line every thing works fine. This is the log record for the above command line operation:

```
May 27 15:55:58 xen sSMTP[27763]: Creating SSL connection to host
May 27 15:56:01 xen sSMTP[27763]: SSL connection using RC4-SHA
May 27 15:56:04 xen sSMTP[27763]: Sent mail for emailaddress@gmail.com (221 2.0.0 closing connection ln3sm34863740wjc.8 - gsmtp) uid=0 username=root outbytes=495
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It would be useful that you post the contents of your `/etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf` and `/etc/mail_alert.conf` files.

Anyway, have you tried to include `UseTLS=YES` in `/etc/mail_alert.conf`?

Comment: Unfortunately that system is gone now. So i cannot post these files. And for UseTLS=YES option : yes i tried. (As i remember). Now i use 6.5. As soon as possible i will try that on that system. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't notice that the question was quite old before answering.